# primefaces datatable filter selectCheckboxMenu with bootsfaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, bootsfaces

I am using the primefaces datatable with bootsfaces, and there is a CSS conflict that I would like to work around.

Implementing the filter example from the primefaces showcase:

`http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml`

gives me this result:
[datatable filter example good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ft6s5.png)

However, adding a bootsfaces component to the page, eg (the only change is to add an empty `<b:inputtext>` element):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h:form>
            <b:inputText></b:inputText>

            <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtFilterView.cars}" widgetVar="carsTable"
                         emptyMessage="No cars found with given criteria" filteredValue="#{dtFilterView.filteredCars}">

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:outputPanel>
                        <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
                        <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('carsTable').filter()" style="width:150px" placeholder="Enter keyword"/>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </f:facet>

                <p:column filterBy="#{car.id}" headerText="Id" footerText="contains" filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column filterBy="#{car.year}" headerText="Year" footerText="lte" filterMatchMode="lte">
                    <f:facet name="filter">
                        <p:spinner onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()" styleClass="year-spinner">
                            <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Integer" />
                        </p:spinner>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column filterBy="#{car.brand}" headerText="Brand" footerText="exact" filterMatchMode="exact" filterStyle="width: 100px">
                    <f:facet name="filter">
                        <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()" >
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{dtFilterView.brands}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column filterBy="#{car.color}" headerText="Color" footerText="in" filterMatchMode="in" filterStyle="margin-bottom 0px">
                    <f:facet name="filter">
                        <p:selectCheckboxMenu label="Colors" onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()" panelStyle="width:125px" scrollHeight="150">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{dtFilterView.colors}" />
                        </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column filterBy="#{car.sold}" headerText="Status" footerText="equals" filterMatchMode="equals">
                    <f:facet name="filter">
                        <p:selectOneButton onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()">
                            <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Boolean" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sold" itemValue="true" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sale" itemValue="false" />
                        </p:selectOneButton>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.sold ? 'Sold': 'Sale'}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column filterBy="#{car.price}" headerText="Price" footerText="custom (min)" filterFunction="#{dtFilterView.filterByPrice}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.price}">
                        <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="$" type="currency"/>
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

gives this result:
[primefaces datatable filter style error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAYZb.png)

The dropdown box for the filters has its margin changed, causing the down arrow to not be in the correct position. The text is also reduced to 0.85.

Is there a way that I can combine bootsfaces with primefaces datatable and maintain the primefaces drop-down menu formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Stephan - great work on bootsfaces btw, it's a lot of fun to program with.

Your changes didn't quite match the primefaces example on my system, but they were an improvement, and gave me a good insight into how to make my own changes.

Using these style overrides worked better on my system:

```
<style>
        .ui-widget {
            font-size: 16px !important;
        }

        .ui-selectcheckboxmenu-label {
           margin-bottom: 0px;
        }

        .ui-selectcheckboxmenu-trigger {
            width: auto !important;
        }

        .ui-selectonemenu-trigger {
            width: auto !important;                
        }

        .ui-selectcheckboxmenu-label {
            font-weight: normal !important;
        }
        label{
            font-weight: normal !important;                
        }
        body {
            line-height: 18px !important;
        }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect yet, but adding these few lines of CSS code make the BootsFaces version look almost perfectly like the original, PrimeFaces-only version:

```
    <h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
    <style>
    .ui-widget {
        font-size: 17.6px !important;
    }

    * {
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
        box-sizing: content-box !important;
    }

    *:before, *:after {
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
        box-sizing: content-box !important;
    }

    body {
        margin: 8px !important;
    }
    </style>
    </h:head>
```

However, most of these settings might affect the BootsFaces components. Setting the font size to 0.85 is almost certainly a bug in BootsFaces, which we're going to solve, but the other settings look like different approaches to resetting the CSS default settings of the browser. In other words: fixing the look and feel of complex PrimeFaces component might ruin the look and feel of BootsFaces components.